# Where is $x=\frac{a+b+c+d}{4}$ in $0<a<b<c<d<e$?

Tags: inequality, order-statistics

Where is the exact position of  $x=\frac{a+b+c+d}{4}$ in $0<a<b<c<d<e$?

## The real problem

I have a box-and-whisker plot. It shows

- $L$ : the min value.
- $Q_1$ : the lower quartile.
- $Q_2$ : the median (a.k.a the second quartile).
- $Q_3$ : the upper quartile.
- $R$ : the max value.

I think we cannot find the exact position of the mean $\bar{x}$ but I am interested in finding the tight bound in which the mean can be.

I guess the bound (it might not be so tight) is

$$
\frac{L+Q_1+Q_2+Q_3}{4}\leq \bar{x} \leq \frac{Q_1+Q_2+Q_3+R}{4}
$$

That seems to be useless as well.

Comment: $\frac{a+b+c+d}{4}=\frac{a+b}{2}\times \frac{c+d}{2}$ is wrong.

Comment: $x$ can be anywhere between $a$ and $d$ and your calculation is wrong.

Comment: The mean value is between $a$ and $d$, and I doubt that more can be said.

Comment: You have changed the question completely into a different one now. That’s a NO.

Comment: In your new problem, you need the distribution function to determine the mean. It does not need to be even between the first and third quartiles.

Comment: @Macavity: How to find the distribution function?

Comment: You can’t find it from the data provided, it has to be also specified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can’t tell; the most you can say is that x is between a and d. Also i don’t see how point e is significant.

One way to think about what it means geometrically is to take the center of gravity of the points; imagine putting 4 equal sized weights at a b c d on a number line.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to say. It depends on the actual values of $a,b,c,d$. Depending on the dispersion of $a,b,c,d$, the average $(a+b+c+d)/4$ can be anywhere between $a$ and $d$.